# Installing .zip packages with the MiKTeX package manager from a local repository

Tags: miktex

I'm in a network where I have to use local package repository. I would like to add some packages to this repository so that all computers using this repository can install it via the MiKTeX package manager. It seems to work fine with some packages, but .zip-packages are not listed in the MiKTeX package manager, even though they are copied to the local repository directory.

The specific packages are from texample:

- http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/zip/tikz-dsp.zip
- http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/signalflowlibrary/signalflowlibrary.zip

How can I make the package manager listing these packages from my local directory?

Comment: MiKTeX's package manage can only install packages in MiKTeX format. For adding non-packaged material to an installation, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows (possible dupe) and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then the plan that everyone can easily add it via the package manager won't work out anyway. For a single installation solution adding the unpacked archive to MiKTeX roots is sufficient.